# how to open pdf that is stored in download folder on nougat .I am trying this code but it shows Blanck Screen

Tags: android

how to open pdf that is stored in download folder on nougat .I am trying this code but it shows Blanck Screen

```
File pdfFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory((Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)) + "/hello.pdf");
    Uri path  = 

    FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(),"prsc.puda", pdfFile);
        Intent pdfIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        pdfIntent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
        pdfIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        try{
            startActivity(pdfIntent);
        }catch(ActivityNotFoundException e){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Application available to view PDF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```